# linq-to-sql null or default

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
var TheQuery = (from....
               where x.TheDate >= StartDate && x.TheDate <= EndDate
               select new MyModel()
               {
                   Total = (int?)x.Count() ?? 0,
                   ....
               }).Single();
```

Basically, I'm querying a number of records based between 2 dates. If for the date there are 0 values, it returns 0 as the Total. However, if there are no values at all, it returns null and crashes. I could add `.SingleOrDefault()` but it would return null instead of MyModel populated with a 0. The property Total is defined as an int.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the entire query?

Comment: @OskarKjellin: that's pretty much it, the from clause sets a table and the other properties are of the same kind: fill an int with a count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count has an overload with a predicate, and returns 0 when no item matches the predicate

```
 var result = new MyModel {
                          Total = <yourDataSource>
                            .Count(x.TheDate >= StartDate && x.TheDate <= EndDate)
                          };
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Just add `()` in the `new MyModel` and that's it! ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(TheQuery !=null || TheQuery .Count()>0){
 //do something you wanna do
```

}

or

```
 var v = TheQuery.ToList();
```

now check

```
if (v.Count > 0)
```

Comment: That's messy, can't I just specify it in the query itself instead of adding conditions around the query?

Answer (score 0):

You should opt for:

```
int count = (from x in ...
where x.TheDate >= StartDate && x.TheDate <= EndDate
select c).Count();
```

That's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var TheQuery = (from....
               where x.TheDate >= StartDate && x.TheDate <= EndDate
               select new MyModel()
               {
                   Total = (int?)x.Count() ?? 0,
                   ....
               }).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Single()'
```